# QField not saving location data

Tags: qgis, gps, qfield, geolocation

I'm a total newbie at this, volunteering in a survey project.
We're using QGIS and QField with SinoGNSS hardware and Survey Master running in the background.

For some reason, when saving a location in QField, the location data (coming from the SinoGNSS hardware through Survey master) isn't getting saved. It goes through the usual process, a photo is taken, the date is entered, and the green tick pressed, and - nothing.

How can I solve this?